# Is it possible to prevent higher order function execution in Jest test, if passed callback is a mock?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I have a function which makes a lot of calculations and returns order of sorting. For that function I have tests. Then, that function is used inside of JS native sort method. In that case, I mock my compare function, just to test if it was called with proper parameters.

Code looks like this:

```
const output = Object.keys(options).sort(compare(param1, param2));
```

`compare` here is a mock, I check if it was called, check if it was called with proper params.

Is it possible to stop sort execution, or it automatically stops, when it sees it's a mock? I couldn't find any source, that will match my question.

Comment: As far as I know you can not prevent/cancel the function call once startet. It still runs if you have no return aka `undefined` for each entry. Yet the order itself does not alter if you have no return.

Comment: If your mock threw an error execution would stop. Otherwise you'd have to have logic in your production code to determine if a mock was being used, which would be horrible. But I'm not sure you should be writing this test at all. Assert that the results are in the right order, test _behaviour_ not implementation details.

Comment: @Lain So it means, in the test sort can be just by itself and won't interfere?

Comment: @jonrsharpe mock and production code are incompatible.  Mocks are used in tests, tests don't go to production. 

The problem is, compare function has many conditions inside, for all of them there are tests already. Here, I don't want to make every single outcome, it will take me very long and its useless. 
The logic is this: native sort function tested and works, compare function tested and works, and in this case I just need to check, if compare function is called.

Comment: Yes, I understand that mocks are used in tests, my point is that _"it automatically stops, when sees its a mock?"_ would require the code _under_ test to be checking whether or not a mock was in use. _"compare function has many conditions inside"_ - which is irrelevant, since in the case you're talking about it's mocked out.

Comment: @Tigran Petrosyan That is my assumption. I did not find any documentation that actually states it.